# German language pack for Zikula 1.5.7

Tags: zikula

I just installed Zikula 1.5.7. Now I'm looking for a german language pack for this version of Zikula. Where can I find it?

Regards from Berlin
Jens

Comment: Resource requests are off-topic on [so]. Your question may be on-topic on [softwarerecs.se], but please do make sure to read their on-topic and off-topic pages, help center, and FAQ, and browse the questions to get a feeling for the kinds of questions the SR.SE community feels appropriate. I am not familiar with that community, but from what I know, they require a clear specification of the requirements for the software.

Comment: SO is a main source of support for Zikula. In my view, this is not an inappropriate topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find these files at https://github.com/zikula-communities/german/tree/core-1.5
In addition you may want to join the Zikula slack at https://joinslack.zikula.de/ to get more direct support.